# How to query table which name can be only obtained by another query

Tags: google-bigquery

Let's say we have a terrible design in BigQuery, which should have never been created that way, like the following:
`some_project` contains dataset `metadata`, which contains table `metadata`. Sample data for `some_project.metadata.metadata`:

```
| dataset_id |
| xyz1234567 |
| zzz8562042 |
| vyz0009091 |
```

For each `dataset_id` I need to query `some_table` in this dataset, for example `some_project.xyz1234567.some_table`.

Is this possible to query these multiple tables in a single query? I'm looking for getting aggregate results for each table.
In other words, I'm trying to say something like that:

```
SELECT SUM(table.x) from table WHERE table IN
(SELECT CONCAT('some_project.', dataset_id, 'some_table') FROM `some_project.metadata.metadata`)
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(table.x) FROM
(SELECT CONCAT('some_project.', dataset_id, 'some_table' as table FROM `some_project.metadata.metadata`)
```

I know that no one should ever need to do something like this, but the design I described above is something I just have to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider this approach using a temporary table as a SQL cursor alternative with the help of BigQuery looping statements.

You can read row by row and execute the query of each table name.

Here you can see this example:

```
DECLARE var1 INT64 DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE var2 INT64 DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE str1 string DEFAULT '';
DECLARE str2 string DEFAULT '';
DECLARE str3 string DEFAULT '';

CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_emp AS
SELECT empid, 
    ename, 
    deptid,
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY empid) rownum
FROM   td.emp1; 


SET var2= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_emp);

WHILE var2<=var1 DO
  SET str1 = (SELECT empid FROM temp_emp WHERE rownum = x);
  SET str2 = (SELECT empid FROM temp_emp WHERE rownum = x);
  SET str3 = (SELECT empid FROM temp_emp WHERE rownum = x);

  SET var1=var1+1;

END WHILE;
```

Following are some of points to be noted.

- We are using the SET command to assign value to a variable. It is
  SELECT..INTO in the original example.
- We are not using open and close cursor.
- We are creating a TEMPORARY table in place of cursor declaration.

You can see more documentation in [this link](https://dwgeek.com/what-is-sql-cursor-alternative-in-bigquery.html/).

Comment: Thank you for that technique. I hoped for something cleaner, but now I see that BigQuery doesn't support things like cursor variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
declare sql string;
set sql = (
            select concat("Select something from 
            someproject.",datasetid,".sometable"
    ) from metadata.metadata);

execute immediate sql
```

[EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate)

Comment: This doesn't work. I think you're mixing two things here. One is scalar subquery, which you can't use when you need to construct the table with concat, the other thing is execute immediate, which works but you need to quote the whole query.
However, it takes little changes to make it working:
`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT SUM(the_field_I_need_the_sum_of) FROM ' || table_for_study INTO result;`

Comment: Execute immediate is for running dynamic sqls. So if you could paste what you ran and error here, i can help.

Comment: As I wrote above, I solved the problem with the error. The query I pasted in my last comment, runs without the error.